# Normally distributed random variables on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, math

I've been looking on Google/stackoverflow for a couple of hours and I can't find a way (or even a gem) to generate normally distributed random variables using ruby on rails. It's a bit frustrating..!
Any idea ?

Comment: Time for you to write a gem :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code to generate Gaussian (normally distributed) random numbers in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825680/code-to-generate-gaussian-normally-distributed-random-numbers-in-ruby)

Comment: http://rubygems.org/gems/distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help in comments. Oli is right, I found the answer in that answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8205982/2576033

Using rubystats gem - "a port of the statistics libraries from PHPMath" (pure ruby), you can generate normally distributed variables, easily and in a nice way :

```
gen = Rubystats::NormalDistribution.new(mean, sd)
gen.rng               # a single random sample
gen.rng(100)          # 100 random samples
```